# What does "steenkeenk mirrors" mean here?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

So, hey, toss Universal Consciousness! Just to be sure.
Awareness don nee no steenkeenk mirrors!

What does "steenkeenk mirrors" mean here?

And one more question :
I read this article from quora..my question what does "toss Universal Consciousness"interpret according this article?

he said with live conscious or
he said live without conscious???

https://www.quora.com/What-is-true-nothingness/answer/Edg-Duveyoung

can anyone explain this simply..my english is poor..I get really confused.

Thankyou.

Comment: It's an imitation of a non-native speaker (Italian?) saying in broken English "doesn't need any stinking mirrors", but I don't know if it's a reference to a particular character.

Answer (score 3):

It is a reference to "[We don't need no steenking badges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinking_badges)" in various films.

And *toss* means "throw away".